# Could not find member 'intellectualPropertyPublisher' on object of type 'JobProperties' in Azure Machine Learning Designer

Tags: azure-machine-learning-service

From today (Aug 24th, 2021) I'm receiving the following error message when submit any operation in Azure Machine Learning Designer with a dataset:

**Could not find member 'intellectualPropertyPublisher' on object of type 'JobProperties'**

Complete error message:

*UserError: Job submission to AzureML Compute encountered an Exception with status code , Could not find member 'intellectualPropertyPublisher' on object of type 'JobProperties'. Path 'properties.intellectualPropertyPublisher', line 309, position 36.*

I'm seeing there's new items in user interface, maybe could be an updating error?
Someone is receiving something that?

Comment: This sounds like an internal error. Was this happening before? Is it happening again now consistently? Can you share a GitHub Gist of the full error log?

Comment: Hi @AndersSwanson, after a few hours the problem was resolved, maybe it was an internal error as you said. Regards!